# How do add an exception to preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following preg_match;

```
preg_match('=^\d?[a-z]{1,2}\d{1,4}[a-z]{1,3}$=i', $mystring);
```

This works great but I have some mystrings that have a /H or some other character. They also might end in -1, or -15 or other numbers.

Mystrings can look like this W0DLK, WA0DLK, W0DLK-1, W0DLK-20, W0DLK/H, W0DLK/M

How would I add to my existing preg_match to ignore anything after the '-' dash or the '/' slash? Substringing the value first would be difficult in my use.

Comment: Valid values would look like this: W0DLK, WA0DLK, W0DLK/H, W0DLK/any letter here, W0DLK-15, or any number after the dash.

Comment: Your first solution (below) worked the best. Thank you!!                         return preg_match('=^\d?[a-z]{1,2}\d{1,4}[a-z]{1,3}(?:[-/][a-z\d]+)?$=i', $callsign);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an optional capture group at the end of your expression so the hyphen/dash and characters are allowed.

```
^\d?[a-z]{1,2}\d{1,4}[a-z]{1,3}(?:[-/][a-z\d]+)?$
```

This allowed a `-` or `/` and then letters and/or numbers. A stricter regex would be:

```
^\d?[a-z]{1,2}\d{1,4}[a-z]{1,3}(?:-\d+|/[a-z]+)?$
```

This allows the string to end with a `-` and numbers, or a `/` and letters.

1. https://regex101.com/r/6OxdZC/1/
2. https://regex101.com/r/6OxdZC/2/

Comment: Ooops! Found an issue. There can only be one number in the value being tested. For example W5DLK, WA5DLK, WA5DLK/H, etc. And no more than 3 characters after the number.

Comment: Per your original regex the second regex should be able to be modified to accommodate. Change `+` after `\d` to `{1,3}` and remove `+` after `[a-z]`... if I've read this right.